# What is this strange icon?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

Anyone know what this icon at the upper left is?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you might want to drag the notification panel and check.this looks like a notification from some app.

Comment: Looks like a check mark with an underline that's on top of a part of your wallpaper.

Comment: @touchstone   Please mention your device name. May be some video editing tools, please check whether you have similar apps.

Comment: This is exactly the image size we need when trying to identify a very small icon on the top of your screen. Can you send a better screenshot where we don't have to guess what the icon is even trying to show? (I see two location markers on a street)

Comment: 1) it's not my wallpaper. 2) there aren't any notification messages. 3) my device is a xiaomi redmi note 5 pro, with AEX rom installed. I don't have any video editing apps.

Answer (score 2):

The checkmark with an underline is the download completed icon (when an app downloads something using the download manager). The 3 circles are a part of the wallpaper

Comment: Nothing downloaded and the circles are not part of my wallpaper. It's an icon. It disappears. And it reappears. It does so at what seems random. There's no observable pattern here. I don't understand why anyone would vote the answer correct except me. I'm obviously the only person who can confirm correctness of any answers.

Comment: @touchstone well I can't comment on the 3 circles but the checkmark is definitely a download compete icon. Check your notification history? https://www.howtogeek.com/242073/how-to-view-notifications-youve-dismissed-on-android/

Comment: I checked the history. Nothing is registered as happening at the times the icon appears.

Comment: Have you enabled any custom icons in the status bar? Resurrection Remix would allow me to put icons there and sometimes it'd bug out displaying icons over one another